# How to capture a button click in the original activity instead of the ListAdapter

Tags: android, listadapter

I have an activity called MoviesActivity that uses a ListAdapter called MovieAdapter to display a list of movies. Each list item has name etc., and a button which the user can click to play the movie. My question is - how do I shift the onClick code associated with the button from the MovieAdapter class to the MoviesActivity class?

```
public class MoviesActivity extends Activity{
    private static final String TAG = "MoviesActivity";
    public ListView listView; 
    public MovieAdapter movieAdapter;
      ...

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.movies);

      listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MovieListView);
      moviesManager = new MoviesManager(client);
      List<Movie> allMoviesList = moviesManager.getAllMoviesList();      


      movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter((Context)this, allMoviesList,moviesManager);
      listView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);

}
```

The code for MovieAdapter

```
 public class MovieAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener{
      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          ...
      }
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) { 
         //Play movie
          ...
      }
 }
```

My MovieAdapter is fully functioning. My question is - I would like to write the code to play the movie in MoviesActivity and not in MovieAdaptor. How can I do that? I have had similar problems many times but never found a good technique (other than using static methods etc.) The problem comes when I try to issue a getWindow() inside onClick - which it wouldn't since its not in a Activity subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing a `Context` object into your `MovieAdapter` constructor, pass in the `MovieActivity` object and run the `MovieActivity`'s `playMovie(Movie)` method from the button's `OnClick` event:

Your Activity:

```
public class MoviesActivity extends Activity {
    public ListView listView; 
    public MovieAdapter movieAdapter;

    //...

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.movies);

       listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MovieListView);
       moviesManager = new MoviesManager(client);
       List<Movie> allMoviesList = moviesManager.getAllMoviesList();      

       movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(this, allMoviesList, moviesManager);
       listView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
    }

    public void playMovie(Movie movie) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Your Adapter:

```
public class MovieAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
      private MoviesActivity mActivity;
      private List<Movie> mMovies;
      private MoviesManager mClient;

      // ...

      public MovieAdapter(MoviesActivity activity, List<Movie> allMovies, 
              MoviesManager client) {
          mActivity = activity;
          mMovies = allMovies;
          mClient = client;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

          final Movie movie = mMovies.get(position);

          // ...

          myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) { 
                  mActivity.playMovie(movie);
              }
          });
      }
 }
```

Comment: I don't know why it never occurred to me that I can instantiate Activities too! Thanks, a lot! (no reputation right now to up vote your answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you can extend ListActivity instead of activity you can simply do:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
   super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
```

}

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29

Comment: The user will click a button inside the list item and not the list item.