# Handle ListView row button click when using common RowLayout

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

I've a single `ListAdapter` and `ListView` `RowLayout` which I used in 2 fragments having `ListView`s. The problem is how to handle the `ListView` item row button click. There are 2 buttons in the common `RowLayout` and these buttons will have the same functions irrespective of the fragment being displayed. I searched for it and found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630615/how-to-capture-a-button-click-in-the-original-activity-instead-of-the-listadapte). But in this post button click calls one activity only while I have two fragments. So how do we make sure in Adapter to call a particular fragment from whose layout button is clicked?

`ListAdapter`:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GridItem> {

    private Context mContext;
    int resource;
    private ArrayList<GridItem> mListData = new ArrayList<GridItem>();

    public ListAdapter(Context mContext, int resource, ArrayList<GridItem> mListData) {
        super(mContext, resource, mListData);
        this.resource = resource;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mListData = mListData;
    }

    public void setListData(ArrayList<GridItem> mListData) {
        this.mListData = mListData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public GridItem getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();

            v = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
            holder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            holder.regtdemail = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_regtdemail);
            holder.follow = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.follow);
            holder.remove = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.remove);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }


        GridItem item = mListData.get(position);
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(item.getImage())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .fit()
                .into(holder.image);
        holder.name.setText(item.getName());
        holder.regtdemail.setText(item.getRegtdEmail());
        holder.follow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        holder.remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });


        return v;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        TextView name, regtdemail;
        Button follow, remove;
    }

}
```

2nd fragment:

```
public class SuggestFriend extends Fragment{

    private ListView mListView;
    private GridItem newItem;
    private ListAdapter mListAdapter;
    private ArrayList<GridItem> mGridData;
    public static final String KEY_USERID = "user_id", SPORTS_ID = "sports_id";
    private static final String MUTUAL_FOLLOWERS = "http://example.com/api/member/follow-suggestions/";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.suggestfriend, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        mGridData = new ArrayList<>();
        mListAdapter = new ListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.common_row, mGridData);
        mListView.setAdapter(mListAdapter);

        loadmutualfollowers();

    }

    private void loadmutualfollowers() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, MUTUAL_FOLLOWERS,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);

                            System.out.println(jObj);

                            String status = jObj.getString("status");

                            // Now check status value
                            if (status.equals("0")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "There was some error! Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else if (status.equals("1")) {


                                JSONArray result = jObj.getJSONArray("result");
                                for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject json_data = result.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String name = json_data.getString("name");
                                    String regtdemail = json_data.getString("username");
                                    String user_id = json_data.getString("user_id");

                                    newItem = new GridItem();

                                    newItem.setName(name);
                                    newItem.setRegtdEmail(regtdemail);
                                    newItem.setUserId(user_id);
                                    if(json_data.has("profile_picture")){

                                        newItem.setImage(json_data.getString("profile_picture"));

                                    }else{

                                        Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.sam.fitlincsearch/" + R.drawable.default_profile);
                                        String image_def = path.toString();
                                        newItem.setImage(image_def);

                                    }


                                    mGridData.add(newItem);
                                }


                                mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            } else {
                                String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // JSON error
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "VolleyError" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_USERID, "1");  
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

1st fragment:

```
public class TopContenders extends Fragment {

    private ListView mListView;
    private GridItem newItem;
    private ListAdapter mListAdapter;
    private ArrayList<GridItem> mGridData;
    public static final String KEY_USERID = "user_id", SPORTS_ID = "sports_id";
    private static final String TOP_MEMBERS = "http://example.com/api/top-member/";
    Button follow, unfollow;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.topcontenders, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        mGridData = new ArrayList<>();
        mListAdapter = new ListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.common_row, mGridData);
        mListView.setAdapter(mListAdapter);

        loadtopmembers();
    }

    private void loadtopmembers() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, TOP_MEMBERS,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);

                            System.out.println(jObj);

                            String status = jObj.getString("status");

                            // Now check status value
                            if (status.equals("0")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "There was some error! Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else if (status.equals("1")) {


                                JSONArray result = jObj.getJSONArray("result");
                                for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject json_data = result.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String name = json_data.getString("name");
                                    String regtdemail = json_data.getString("username");
                                    String user_id = json_data.getString("user_id");
                                    String sports_id = json_data.getString("sports_id");

                                    newItem = new GridItem();

                                    newItem.setName(name);
                                    newItem.setRegtdEmail(regtdemail);
                                    newItem.setUserId(user_id);
                                    if(json_data.has("profile_picture")) {
                                        newItem.setImage(json_data.getString("profile_picture"));

                                    }else{

                                        Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.sam.fitlincsearch/" + R.drawable.default_profile);
                                        String image_def = path.toString();
                                        newItem.setImage(image_def);

                                    }
                             /*     if(sports_id.equals("1")){
                                      newItem.setSportsId("Weight");
                                  }else if(sports_id.equals("2")){
                                      newItem.setSportsId("Cycle");
                                  }else if(sports_id.equals("3")){
                                      newItem.setSportsId("Swim");
                                  }else if(sports_id.equals("4")){
                                      newItem.setSportsId("Run");
                                  } */

                                    mGridData.add(newItem);
                                }


                                mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            } else {
                                String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // JSON error
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "VolleyError" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_USERID, "1");  
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set current view to button in adapter's `getView()` method and in `button.setOnClickListener()` you can get this view and do whatever you want.
Use `setTag()` and `getTag()`.

Example:

In `getView()` of adapter:

```
holder.btnPlus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlusdessert);
    holder.btnPlus.setTag(R.integer.btnplusview,convertView);
```

Button's `onClickListener()`

```
holder.btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View tempView =(View) v.getTag(R.integer.btnplusview);
```

Now you have complete view of row layout and you can get other textview or button or whatever with tempView.

Comment: I don't understand. As you see, in my adapter I've already set up button clicklistener. I just want to make a call request to start a method in whichever fragment layout is being displayed when I click the buttons.

Comment: The method in fragment will start a volley request so I need to call this private method in fragment on button's click event.

Comment: in button's onclick we are getting one view, which will determine which fragment's view is clicked, fragment one or two. In your question you asked how to determine which fragment's view is clicked, so when you click button v.gettag will give you a view of fragment or two, whichever is clicked.